# get JSON response while performing POST request with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

I am using the following code to perform POST requests on a REST API. It is all working fine. What I am being unable to do is after POST is successful the API returns response JSON in body with headers, this JSON has information which I require. I am unable to get the JSON response.

I need this response as this response includes the ID generated by DB. I can see the response while using REST Client plugin of firefox. Need to do implement the same in Java.

[image]

```
    String json = "{\"name\": \"Test by JSON 1\",\"description\": \"Test by JSON 1\",\"fields\": {\"field\": []},\"typeDefinitionId\": \"23\",\"primaryParentId\": \"26982\"}";
    String url = "http://serv23/api/contents";      
    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //Setting the Request Method header as POST
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //Prepairing credentials
    String cred= "user123:p@ssw0rd";
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(cred.getBytes());           
    String credentials = new String(encoded);

    //Setting the Authorization Header as 'Basic' with the given credentials
    con.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

    //Setting the Content Type Header as application/json
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    //Overriding the HTTP method as as mentioned in documentation   
    con.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "POST");

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(json);

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(jsonObject.toJSONString().getBytes());

    os.flush();
    WriteLine( con.getResponseMessage() );
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the input stream and read it.

```
String json_response = "";
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
String text = "";
while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
  json_response += text;
}
```

Comment: after flushing output stream?

Comment: @Moon Yes, `os.flush();` it, then `os.close();`. After that read the response as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())
        );
       String inputLine;
       StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
       }
       in.close();` I am using this tough, a slight variation